# Non-homogeneous linear differential equation with all coefficients equal to $1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider continous function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$

> Solve the following equation: $$y+y^{(r)}+y^{(2r)}+...+y^{(r(k-1))}=f(x)$$
> Where $y=y(x)$, $k,r$ are some natural numbers and $y^{(r)}$ denotes $r$-th derivative of $y$

Here is my attempt:

Firstly i consider homogeneous version of this equation:

$$y+y^{(r)}+y^{(2r)}+...+y^{(r(k-1))}=0$$

Secondly i associate a characteristic polynomial:
$$P(T):=1+T^{r}+T^{2r}+...+T^{(k-1)r}$$
(I notice that this polynomial has exactly $(k-1)r$ distinct roots)

Then the general solution to my original equation schould be in the form
$$y(x)=\sum_{\alpha_: P(\alpha)=0}C(\alpha, x)e^{\alpha x}$$

Now it is sufficient to calculate all the $C(\alpha, x)$ by substituting $y(x)$ into my equation. However i find this difficult.

Thank you in advance